# Trying to read contents of a website but when printed to the logcat only the first 5 lines of code appear

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

**Where I set up the url and HttpUrlConnection which allows the program to read the contents of the url.**

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();
            while(data != -1){
                char current = (char) data;
                result += current;
                data =reader.read();

            }
            return result;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;
    try {
        result = task.execute("http://www.historyplace.com/specials/").get();
        Log.i("Contents of URL", result);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}[image]

**I believe my code is written correctly because the logCat does display a few lines of code. Unfortunately it does not display all of it. I am trying to first retrieve all of the code so I can use Regex to extract certain pictures and names for an educational school project.**

Comment: debug and see the value of result variable. logcat prints only a few lines if the data is huge.

Comment: Im not too familiar with android studios but when I click debug the app runs but unfortunately no variables are printed to the console....

Comment: Like @drulabs said-  logcat truncates the output.  Put a breakpoint and look at the value of the string in the debugger.